# Generate a hash string from a set of variables

Tags: php, hash

How can I generate a hash with let's say md5 from set of mixed variables?

The variables can be of any type, like multidimensional arrays, objects, integers etc.

The idea is to be able to identify within a function if the given arguments are exactly the same as the ones in the previous function call.

This would work but not for all type of vars:

```
$args = func_get_args();
$args = array_values($args);
echo md5(implode('', $args));
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need to remember whether a function has been called with certain parameters? Perhaps there's a better solution to your problem.

Comment: I need to know if I need to generate the output of certain functions or just pull it out from cache

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you just need `md5(serialize($yourvar));`.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: +1 Of course this requires all parameters to be serializable, but there's really no way to get around that. The notes in the function detail the requirements for serializability and explain how to make your own classes serializable (which they might be already).